# How do I make text that looks like it is made out of a ribbon?

Tags: modeling

[image: Anyone Guide me. I am a beginner of Blender, i want to make 3d image like below one, i have created 50 of this image (except 2 ribbon curve), and i used modifier tools too. Kindly give me better tuts]

Anyone Guide me. I am a beginner of Blender, i want to make 3d image like below one, i have created 50 of this image (except 2 ribbon curve), and i used modifier tools too. Kindly give me better tuts

Comment: Use a bezier curve following the global shape you want, then assign it a bevel object (a segment may be ok here). After that you'll probably have to adjust the twist (ctrl+T) and the weights (alt+S) of the bezier curve's control points.

Comment: Can you please send work area what you have mention, i already done. in front view is not good to seeing above one

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a tutorial request.

Comment: Guys, in my opinion, on 4 answers I gave on the last 24 hours, 3 can be considered to be an answer to a tutorial request, more or less.

Comment: It's fantastic... Tut's... Very useful

Answer (score 4):

The base is to use a Bezier curve with a bevel object (which needs to be a curve too).

For the overall shape curve, add it by : <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> then choose 'curve' and 'Bezier'.

For the ribbon curve, add it the same way and flatten it : enter edit mode <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then scale it 0 along Y (as its shape is by default curved on Y) <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>.

Come back to object mode <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

At this step, you have two curves like this :

[image]

Now select the first one (overall shape curve) and assign it the second curve as bevel object (in the geometry part of the curve tab, as shown below) :

[image]

You can see that the ribbon curve is propagated along the overall shape curve.

But the ribbon is a bit large, so scale it down a bit : select the ribbon curve and scale it down <kbd>S</kbd> and move the mouse :

[image]

Now all is about extruding the overall shape curve. 
Select it, enter edit mode, select an extremity vertex (control point) and type <kbd>E</kbd> and move the mouse.

[image]

Alternatively, you can also extrude with <kbd>LMB</kbd> holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key simultaneously.

[image]

Eventually, you may need to subdivide some parts. Same can be done selecting two control points and with <kbd>W</kbd> then subdivide :

[image]

With these basic operations, you can 'draw' your shape.

Last operations to know :

You will need to twist your curve <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> then move the mouse:

[image]

And you will need to adjust the ribbon size <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> then move the mouse:

[image]

Comment: lemon.  thank you for your timely help...